# How can I access a request and response with a decorator?

Tags: python, flask

I want to write a custom decorator to get metrics from an endpoint, is there a way for me to access the request as well as a response from a decorator? If not how should I go about this.

I would like to see the request so I can log it for analysis later and then I would need to see the response to decide what type of response it is. below is my code. The idea is I would be able to reach into the func thats called within inner to grab the request.

Code:

```
def metric(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("*" * 30)
        start = time.process_time()
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        latency = start - time.process_time()
        print(func)
        print("*" * 30)
        print(latency)

    return inner




@metric
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def printer():
    req = request.get_json()
    return req
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do something along the lines of:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
from timeit import default_timer

@contextmanager
def ProcessTimer():
    start = default_timer()
    elapser = lambda: default_timer() - start
    yield lambda: elapser()
    end = default_timer()
    elapser = lambda: end-start
```

and then use it like follows:

```
with ProcessTimer() as elapsed:
    # . . . . . . Code Under Test . . . . . . . . 
    # - - - Do something here that you want to time - - - 
    # . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 
print(f'Solution: derived in {elapsed():.8f} seconds')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to return a valid response in your `inner` function
2. You need to put `metric` decorator under `app.route` decorator

I made some changes to your code based on the 2 points above, you may refer as below:

```
def metric(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("*" * 30)
        start = time.process_time()
        res = func(*args, **kwargs) # get result from func()
        latency = start - time.process_time()
        print(func)
        print("*" * 30)
        print(latency)
        return res # return result
    return inner


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@metric
def printer():
    return 'Hello Flask'
```